# Facing issue while compiling my kernel module with kernel 6.2.0-26-generic

Tags: kernel, compiling, linux-headers

I am building kernel module, my module was working properly with kernel 5.x versions, but now I am getting so many errors during the compilation process from the kernel headers.

errors:

Error from Type.h,Throwing extra braces group at the end of initializer

[image]

error: ‘CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSETUL’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL’?:

[image]

topology.h:

[image]

mm.h:

[image]

vmstat.h:

[image]

vmstat.h:

[image]

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h:425,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/bitops.h:68,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/log2.h:12,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/div64.h:55,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/div64.h:75,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/math.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/math64.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/bitops/instrumented-non-atomic.h: In function ‘__instrument_read_write_bitop’:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/bitops/instrumented-non-atomic.h:66:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘IS_ENABLED’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   66 |         if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_KCSAN_ASSUME_PLAIN_WRITES_ATOMIC)) {
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/bitops/instrumented-non-atomic.h:66:24: error: ‘CONFIG_KCSAN_ASSUME_PLAIN_WRITES_ATOMIC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   66 |         if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_KCSAN_ASSUME_PLAIN_WRITES_ATOMIC)) {
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/bitops/instrumented-non-atomic.h:66:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/cache.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h: At top level:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/cache.h:8:26: error: ‘CONFIG_X86_L1_CACHE_SHIFT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
    8 | #define L1_CACHE_SHIFT  (CONFIG_X86_L1_CACHE_SHIFT)
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/cache.h:9:31: note: in expansion of macro ‘L1_CACHE_SHIFT’
    9 | #define L1_CACHE_BYTES  (1 << L1_CACHE_SHIFT)
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/cache.h:13:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘L1_CACHE_BYTES’
   13 | #define SMP_CACHE_BYTES L1_CACHE_BYTES
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/cache.h:41:58: note: in expansion of macro ‘SMP_CACHE_BYTES’
   41 | #define ____cacheline_aligned __attribute__((__aligned__(SMP_CACHE_BYTES)))
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/percpu-defs.h:148:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘____cacheline_aligned’
  148 |         ____cacheline_aligned
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:37:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘DECLARE_PER_CPU_ALIGNED’
   37 | DECLARE_PER_CPU_ALIGNED(struct pcpu_hot, pcpu_hot);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h:269,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/jump_label.h:255,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/cpuid.h:9,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:20:44: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
   20 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_read(const atomic64_t *v)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/build_bug.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h: In function ‘arch_atomic64_read’:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:22:31: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
   22 |         return __READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
      |                               ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:341:27: note: in definition of macro ‘__unqual_scalar_typeof’
  341 |                 _Generic((x),                                           \
      |                           ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:22:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   22 |         return __READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/rwonce.h:1,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler.h:247,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/build_bug.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:22:31: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
   22 |         return __READ_ONCE((v)->counter);
      |                               ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:44:73: note: in definition of macro ‘__READ_ONCE’
   44 | #define __READ_ONCE(x)  (*(const volatile __unqual_scalar_typeof(x) *)&(x))
      |                                                                         ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h:269,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/jump_label.h:255,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/cpuid.h:9,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h: At top level:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:32:38: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
   32 | static inline void arch_atomic64_set(atomic64_t *v, s64 i)
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:44:54: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
   44 | static __always_inline void arch_atomic64_add(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                      atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:58:45: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
   58 | static inline void arch_atomic64_sub(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:74:54: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
   74 | static inline bool arch_atomic64_sub_and_test(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                      atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:86:47: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
   86 | static __always_inline void arch_atomic64_inc(atomic64_t *v)
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:100:47: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  100 | static __always_inline void arch_atomic64_dec(atomic64_t *v)
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:116:47: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  116 | static inline bool arch_atomic64_dec_and_test(atomic64_t *v)
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:130:47: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  130 | static inline bool arch_atomic64_inc_and_test(atomic64_t *v)
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:145:54: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  145 | static inline bool arch_atomic64_add_negative(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                      atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:158:60: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  158 | static __always_inline s64 arch_atomic64_add_return(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:164:51: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  164 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_sub_return(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                   atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:170:50: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  170 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_fetch_add(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                  atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:176:50: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  176 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_fetch_sub(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                  atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:182:41: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  182 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_cmpxchg(atomic64_t *v, s64 old, s64 new)
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:188:55: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  188 | static __always_inline bool arch_atomic64_try_cmpxchg(atomic64_t *v, s64 *old, s64 new)
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                       atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:194:38: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  194 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_xchg(atomic64_t *v, s64 new)
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:200:45: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  200 | static inline void arch_atomic64_and(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:208:50: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  208 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_fetch_and(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                  atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:218:44: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  218 | static inline void arch_atomic64_or(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                            atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:226:49: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  226 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_fetch_or(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:236:45: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  236 | static inline void arch_atomic64_xor(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             atomic_t
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic64_64.h:244:50: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’; did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
  244 | static inline s64 arch_atomic64_fetch_xor(s64 i, atomic64_t *v)
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                  atomic_t
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic.h:80,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/jump_label.h:255,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/cpuid.h:9,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1343:34: error: unknown type name ‘atomic64_t’
 1343 | arch_atomic64_read_acquire(const atomic64_t *v)
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/build_bug.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from dscudkp.c:97:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h: In function ‘arch_atomic64_read_acquire’:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1347:27: error: ‘atomic64_t’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘atomic_t’?
 1347 |         if (__native_word(atomic64_t)) {
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:352:17: note: in definition of macro ‘__native_word’
  352 |         (sizeof(t) == sizeof(char) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(short) || \
      |                 ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:44: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                                            ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:341:27: note: in definition of macro ‘__unqual_scalar_typeof’
  341 |                 _Generic((x),                                           \
      |                           ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘smp_load_acquire’
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:44: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                                            ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:365:23: note: in definition of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
  365 |                 if (!(condition))                                       \
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:385:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
  385 |         _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __COUNTER__)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘__native_word’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:49:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert_rwonce_type’
   49 |         compiletime_assert_rwonce_type(x);                              \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/barrier.h:205:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  205 |         __unqual_scalar_typeof(*p) ___p1 = READ_ONCE(*p);               \
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘smp_load_acquire’
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:44: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                                            ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:365:23: note: in definition of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
  365 |                 if (!(condition))                                       \
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:385:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
  385 |         _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __COUNTER__)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘__native_word’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:49:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert_rwonce_type’
   49 |         compiletime_assert_rwonce_type(x);                              \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/barrier.h:205:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  205 |         __unqual_scalar_typeof(*p) ___p1 = READ_ONCE(*p);               \
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘smp_load_acquire’
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:44: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                                            ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:365:23: note: in definition of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
  365 |                 if (!(condition))                                       \
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:385:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
  385 |         _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __COUNTER__)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘__native_word’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:49:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert_rwonce_type’
   49 |         compiletime_assert_rwonce_type(x);                              \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/barrier.h:205:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘READ_ONCE’
  205 |         __unqual_scalar_typeof(*p) ___p1 = READ_ONCE(*p);               \
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘smp_load_acquire’
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h:1348:44: error: request for member ‘counter’ in something not a structure or union
 1348 |                 ret = smp_load_acquire(&(v)->counter);
      |                                            ^~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:365:23: note: in definition of macro ‘__compiletime_assert’
  365 |                 if (!(condition))                                       \
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h:385:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘_compiletime_assert’
  385 |         _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __COUNTER__)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘compiletime_assert’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic/include/asm-generic/rwonce.h:36:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘__native_word’
   36 |         compiletime_assert(__native_word(t) || sizeof(t) == sizeof(long long),  \
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please copy and paste from the terminal into your question and then format the pasted code using markdown formatting: the easiest way is to simply use your mouse cursor to highlight the block of pasted code and then press CTRL+K and this will automatically format it as code. Alternatively, you could place ``` on a blank line directly above or before the pasted code and ``` on a blank line directly after or below the pasted block of code to format it.

Comment: Also alternatively, you could just paste it in and another user like me will format it for you since you are new here. But screenshots are likely to be ignored because then we can't easily copy and paste any of the errors into a search engine. Thanks.